# animation for transform do not work with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im adding animate (transition)for transform but its not working with bootstrap 4

```css
.sub-button {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 2s;
}
.sub-button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
 <button data-song-id="{{$song->id}}"  class="vote-to-collection sub-button btn " value="apply"  >
```

Comment: oh okey i did find the solution thanks

Comment: Then answer your own question here :)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap, by default, has `transition` rule declared for buttons. It would be best if you overrode the rule by higher specificity or by using `!important`

```css
.sub-button {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 2s!important;
}
.sub-button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <button data-song-id="{{$song->id}}"  class="vote-to-collection sub-button btn btn-primary" value="apply">testing</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace `.sub-button` with `.sub-button.btn` to get the animation to work:

```css
.sub-button.btn {
   transform: scale(1);
   transition: transform 2s;
}

.sub-button.btn:hover {
   transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<button data-song-id="{{$song->id}}" class="vote-to-collection sub-button btn" ></button>
```